# Is there a canonical list of Magic Links?

Tags: support, faq

Recently I learned "Magic Links" are a thing

> Paul White: Magic links now work e.g. [mcve] and [example] and [repro] for the new help page
>   [Jul 10 9:45 PM](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/179?m=50980906#50980906)

This is awesome, but I have a nagging feeling there's more of these that I'm not using and very much could be.

Are there more *magic links*? Is there such a list **for this network**? If not, can we make one?

---

> Note: meta.SE appears to have it's [own list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239707/complete-list-of-help-center-magic-links), I'm wondering about network-specific links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Yes

> [This is the official dba.se guidance for canonical links](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) - although it is not guaranteed to be up-to-date (and currently it is slightly out-of-date).

See the comments below this post for a list of magic tags and their renderings. Hover your mouse over the rendered magic link to see a tooltip of the target URL. The follow examples are excluded because they are context-specific.

- `[tag:tagname]`
- `[meta-tag:tagname]`
- `[something.se]`

---

You can find a magic link reference in [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section of SO proper, particularly the [Comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) section. The [dba.se guidance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) does not have the July 10 update at this time.

---

Additionally, Some magic links are only enabled on request. Before we had an MCVE page, there was nothing for `[mcve]` and its synonyms to link to. A [community manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99341/299676) had to create the page then ask a developer to change the code so that `[mcve]` and the others worked on this network. The page that `[mcve]` links to is editable by moderators. The (current) synonyms are `[mcve]`, `[mre]`, `[reprex]`, `[repro]`, & `[example]`. `/help/mcve` and `/help/reprex` urls go to the same page.

<sub>[* from chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52167325#52167325)</sub>

Comment: `[meta]` → [meta] * only functional on `[main]`

Comment: `[main]` → [main]

Comment: `[edit]` → [edit]

Comment: `[help]` → [help]

Comment: `[help/on-topic]` → [help/on-topic]

Comment: `[help/dont-ask]` → [help/dont-ask]

Comment: `[help/behavior]` → [help/behavior]

Comment: `[meta-help]` → [meta-help]

Comment: `[tour]` → [tour]

Comment: `[so]` → [so]   .

Comment: `[pt.so]` → [pt.so]

Comment: `[su]` → [su] .

Comment: `[sf]` → [sf] .

Comment: `[metase]` → [metase]

Comment: `[a51]` → [a51]

Comment: `[se]` → [se] .

Comment: `[chat]` → [chat]

Comment: `[ask]` → [ask]

Comment: `[answer]` → [answer]

Comment: `[mcve]` → [minimal reproducible example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: `[es.so] ` → [es.so]

Comment: `[ru.so]` → [ru.so]