# Magic-link for "Text please, no screencaps"

Tags: feature-request

Can we please get a [magic link](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/is-there-a-canonical-list-of-magic-links) to refer posters to guidance around using text snippets instead of screencaps or other images.

- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

The above meta post provides a canonical text snippet that's a little unwieldy:

`[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)`

However it might not be the worst idea to have a [dba-specific help page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) with links to various fiddle options. Some options for the magic-link keyphrase might be...

- `[text-please]`
- `[no-screencaps]`

Comment: On meta SO there are some requests of this knd and they are always declined. because there is a browser addon that can do that.

Answer (score -3):

My opinion is pointing at https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example would be helpful.

From that page:

> provide the SQL scripts so others don't have to recreate them. Do not provide screenshots of tables or results.

I tried writing some text that would be appropriate for this, however I can't flush it out beyond one or two sentences, hence my recommendation about using the existing page above.

We could fairly easily update the MCVE page to include some reasons why screenshots are bad.

Comment: no in the [mre] is no mention that images aren't helpful to reproduce the problem, it is possible to ocr the image, but the quality is ususal to bad and you have even more work.

Comment: The wording on that page could be updated to include details about why images are bad.